# Removing items from a string

Tags: php

I have the following array called $submissions:

```
Array ( [0] => 342 [1] => 343 [2] => 344 [3] => 345 )
```

I then have a string:

```
$in_both = 342,344;
```

I then am using this code to remove any number thats in $in_both from $submissions:

```
if(($key = array_search($in_both, $submissions)) !== false) {
    unset($submissions[$key]);
}
```

The problem is this is only working for the first number.

How can I have all the numbers removed from the array that are in the variable $in_both?

Thank you

Comment: do you mean $in_both = "342,344"; right?

Comment: how about a `while` loop so it loops while there is a match?

Answer (score 2):

Since `in_both` is a string, you need to convert it to an array:

```
$in_both_arr = explode(",",$in_both);
```

Then you can compare the arrays:

```
$submissions = array_diff($submissions,$in_both_arr);
```

See [documentation](http://php.net/array-diff).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$submissions = Array( 342, 343, 344, 345 );

$in_both = '342,344';

$needles = explode(',', $in_both);
foreach ($needles as $needle) {
    while (($key = array_search($needle, $submissions)) !== false) {
        unset($submissions[$key]);
    }
}
```

The while inside the foreach guarantees that every occurence of the number in the array will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$submissions = array(342, 343, 344, 355);
$in_both     = '342,344';

foreach ( explode(',', $in_both) as $value ) {
  if(($key = array_search($value, $submissions)) !== false) {
    unset($submissions[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `array_search` returns only the first key found, if there are more only the first one will be removed

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `expolde`  function with "," delimiter , and loop through arrary created by `explode` as follow

```
$in_both = "342,344";
$in_both_arr = explode(",",$in_both);
foreach($in_both_arr as $val)
   if(($key = array_search($val, $submissions)) !== false) {
    unset($submissions[$key]);
   }
}
```